# how to display desktop theme on tablets, ipads?

Tags: magento-1.7, theme, regex

I have used the following matched expression for mobile devices..

```
iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini
```

Now mobile version is also coming on tablets and ipads.
could anyone suggest how to use this expression which will bring **the desktop version in tablets and ipad** ?

Answer (score 0):

Try with below string

```
iPhone|iPod|Mobile
```

Desktop theme in tablets and mobile theme only in mobile.

Comment: hi @PrashantValanda.. You mean I have to delete the present expression and use  "iphone|ipod|Mobile ?

Comment: Yes you need to use it

Comment: no...it is not working..

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> iPhone|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini|Fennec|Kindle

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you will not use expressions than it will automatically use your desktop theme in all device. 
Still for using diffrent theme i have done this in magento 1.9 like this just use same expression just change package and theme name you want to use .[image]
For changing package

[image]
For changing Theme

Answer (score 0):

Try This one : I have used it in 1.9.1 .

iPhone|iPod|BlackBerry|Palm|Googlebot-Mobile|mobile|mobi|Windows Mobile|Safari Mobile|Android|Opera Mini

- Just Removed Mobile from your given expression

It will show desktop site in tablets/Desktop and mobile site in mobiles .

Comment: Does it works ?